# Problem implementing 'Auto-Load' feature

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I received some helpful code here on StackOverflow to load the last used document in a Document-Based application. However, I'm new to cocoa and having trouble implementing it. Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    NSURL *lastURL=[[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] recentDocumentURLs] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (lastURL!=nil)
    {
        [docController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil];    
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I'm having trouble with 'docController'. Where do I declare this? I would assume I put this in my header file:

```
IBOutlet NSDocument *docController;
```

But what do I connect it to in IB? I tried dragging it from Files Owner to the Window and it didn't even show up on the drowdown. Or I am I totally lost? Thank you everyone for your help, I'm not sure what I would do without you guys

EDIT:

New Code looks like -

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    NSURL *lastURL=[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil];
    if (lastURL!=nil)
    {
     [docController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil];    
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil];` as in the URL line above.

Comment: Josh,
Thanks for the feedback. I added the revised code above - however, the code is still not working. When I build+run the app, the previous doc doesn't open (even though it shows up @ index 0 in the 'Open Recent'.